# MKMapKit - EXC_BAD_ACCESS when looping through MKAnnotations

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios4, mkmapview, mkannotation

I've been stuck on this EXC_BAD_ACCESS error 2 days now.  I have a `reloadAnnotations` method that removes all annotations before adding new annotations.  Before removing the annotation this method should be checking to see if the new set contains the same location so it's not removed and re-added.  But as soon as I try to trace out the current annotation title I get this error `Thread 1: Program received signal: "EXC_BAD_ACCESS"`

And when I view the annotation in the debugger the title property says "Invalid Summary".  It must be caused by a value not being retained but I've tried everything and can't figure it out.

**Why can't I log the annotation title to NSLog?**

**And why can't I compare each title and coords to other objects?**

BrowseController.m

```
-(void)reloadAnnotations
{
    NSMutableArray *toRemove = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:10];
    for (id annotation in _mapView.annotations) {
        if (annotation != _mapView.userLocation) {
            //ParkAnnotation *pa = (ParkAnnotation *)annotation;
            ParkAnnotation *pa = annotation;
            NSLog(@"pa.title %@", pa.title); // Thread 1: Program received signal: "EXC_BAD_ACCESS"
            [toRemove addObject:annotation];
        }
    }
    // DON'T REMOVE IT IF IT'S ALREADY ON THE MAP!!!!!! 
    for(RKLocation *loc in locations) 
    {
        CLLocationCoordinate2D location;
        location.latitude = (double)[loc.lat doubleValue];
        location.longitude = (double)[loc.lng doubleValue];
        ParkAnnotation *parkAnnotation = [[ParkAnnotation alloc] initWithTitle:loc.name andCoordinate:location];      
        [_mapView addAnnotation:parkAnnotation];
    }
    [_mapView removeAnnotations:toRemove];
}



- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)map viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    NSLog(@"BrowseViewController map viewForAnnotation");
    MKPinAnnotationView *pin = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[_mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier: @"anIdentifier"];

    if (pin == nil){
        pin = [[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation
                                               reuseIdentifier: @"anIdentifier"] autorelease];

        pin.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorRed;
        pin.animatesDrop = YES;
        pin.canShowCallout = YES;
    }
    else{
        pin.annotation = annotation;
    }
    return pin;
    }
```

ParkAnnotation.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface ParkAnnotation : NSObject <MKAnnotation> {

    NSString *title;
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;

}


@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *title;  
@property (nonatomic, readonly) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;

- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)ttl andCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)c2d;

@end
```

ParkAnnotation.m (edited: see Wolfgangs comments below )

```
#import "ParkAnnotation.h"
@implementation ParkAnnotation
@synthesize title, coordinate;
- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)ttl andCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)c2d {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) { 
        title = ttl;
        coordinate = c2d;    
    } 
    return self;
}
- (void)dealloc {
    [title release];
    [super dealloc];
}
@end
```

Comment: You probably can't compare the annotations themselves since they are likely pointers to different objects and therefore never equal. You could try to compare the actual values inside the pointers instead.

Comment: Could you show the *annotations* property of mapview? How do you assign values to this property, are you using the getters and setters or perhaps accessing the property-value directly? Does the property copy or retain it's values?

Comment: @Wolfgang I was intending to compare Annotation titles and the not MKAnnotation object.

Comment: @Wolfgang I can't see _mapView.annotations in the debugger but when I send it to NSLog I see these
    "<ParkAnnotation: 0x5c7c940>",
    "<MKUserLocation: 0x5a4ddb0>"

Comment: Ah, from the documentation I understand it's a build-in property, so I guess the error won't be related to the array itself.

Comment: **Edit: this is the likely cause for the crash:** the initializer in *ParkAnnotation.m* isn't written following ObjC conventions. The *self* variable is never set (`self = [super init]; if (self) { /* custom initialization here ... */ } return self;`) Since self is not set, the accessor methods used in the caller will fail.

Comment: I also thought that would fix it but no luck.  I also added a NSLog to the ParkAnnotation dealloc method and I don't see it being called.

Comment: I updated ParkAnnotation.m in the code above to show your fixes.

Comment: OK I FOUND THE PROBLEM!  Problem A was like you said setting the self variable.  Problem B was changing **title = ttl;** to **self.title = ttl;**

Comment: @Wolfgang add your fix to an answer below and I'll check it for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The initializer in **ParkAnnotation.m** isn't written following ObjC conventions. The *self* variable is never set, the designated initializer of a class should follow the following pattern:

```
- (id)init 
{
    self = [super init]; 
    if (self) 
    { 
        /* custom initialization here ... */ 
    } 
    return self;
}
```

Since *self* is not set, the accessor methods used in the caller will fail; the container object (inside **ParkAnnotation.m** referenced with *self*) will be nil or some bogus value when trying to access a property inside the object from another class.

Comment: The code in *jspooner*'s question is changed since yesterday. In a previous comment I mentioned this problem and *jspooner* changed his code accordingly. He asked me to add this as an answer and he will vote up for it, because it helped him solve his issue.

Comment: oh ok. I was looking at this code and was wondering why self wouldn't be set. And as for his earlier code, it will work save for some rare cases. `self` is set as soon as alloc is done and `[super init]` mostly affects the same chunk of memory. We do `self = [super init]` to make sure that superclass' init method doesn't return something different from what we've allocated like in the case of a singleton. So it should be inside the `if` statement to check whether the assignment failed as we would not want to call `self.*` methods on a different object.

Answer (score 3):

Although you have declared `title` has a `copy` type property, it never is copied as you don't use the setter method and directly assigned. You are even releasing it without ownership. Change it like this,

```
title = [ttl copy];
```

Comment: A better way is to use the property instead of the variable. It would become "self.title = ttl;". It is always prefered to use properties instead of the variables to avoid memory issues. I always start variable names with an _ to prevent these kinds of problems.